# How to create a LintPass that is both Visitor and ExprUseVisitor?

Tags: rust, lint, lifetime, internals

I am currently writing a lint to find places where the use of `std::borrow::Cow` may be beneficial. Those places may include local variables, but also struct fields and enum arguments, unless they are part of the public interface (at which point I intend to bail; I don't want to ask people to change official interfaces at this point).

However, to do this, we have to check the whole crate for definitions before reporting. Since the `LintPass` trait has no callback that is called unconditionally *after* the crate has been walked, I am trying to implement `rustc_front::visit::Visitor` by my own visitor struct that encapsulates the `rustc::lint::Context` and our data.

Furthermore, I want to check fields of type `String` which are somewhere instantiated from a `&'static str`. To make this feasible, I'd like to use the `ExprUseVisitor` trait with my visitor struct.

The code as of now is [here](https://github.com/Manishearth/rust-clippy/blob/8392a05e6de02870a2d7db3966645c2b0f39424e/src/cow.rs).

I get the following error:

```
src/cow.rs:56:44: 56:48 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'v` due to conflicting requirements
src/cow.rs:56         let vis = euv::ExprUseVisitor::new(self as &mut euv::Delegate<'t>, &infcx);
                                                         ^~~~
src/cow.rs:51:5: 58:6 help: consider using an explicit lifetime parameter as shown: fn visit_fn(&mut self, _: FnKind, fd: &FnDecl, b: &Block, _: Span, id: NodeId)
src/cow.rs:51     fn visit_fn(&mut self, _: FnKind, fd: &FnDecl, b: &Block,
src/cow.rs:52             _: Span, id: NodeId) {
src/cow.rs:53         let tcx = &self.cx.tcx;
src/cow.rs:54         let param_env = Some(ty::ParameterEnvironment::for_item(tcx, id));
src/cow.rs:55         let infcx = infer::new_infer_ctxt(tcx, &tcx.tables, param_env, false);
src/cow.rs:56         let vis = euv::ExprUseVisitor::new(self as &mut euv::Delegate<'t>, &infcx);
              ...
```

This error is quite surprising, to say the least. Note that the suggested "explicit lifetime" is actually the same as my code.

So how do I get my code to compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your implementation of `euv::Delegate`.  Specifically, you tried to implement `euv::Delegate<'v> for CowVisitor<'v, 't>` when you meant to implement `euv::Delegate<'t> for CowVisitor<'v, 't>`.

In general, if you're doing anything complicated with lifetimes, the error messages are nearly useless; don't trust that they're actually pointing at the error.